# Music & The Moving Image Conference - NYU, May 20-22, 2011 

Tags: music, sound-design, education, conference, interviews

Despite the name of the symposium, there are many conferences about sound design as well.

So... Are you going? Anyone has attended past conferences?

I would like to meet some of you this summer in NY!!

http://steinhardt.nyu.edu/music/scoring/conference

Answer (score 1):

Sounds rad.  Record some talks and post 'em up!

Comment: Hope to make some interviews too!